# TListview CustomDrawItem change font

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl

I have a listview and would like to change the font color of an item to clRed if the user double clicks on it. However if the user double clicks on another item all other should go back to the black font color and the new double clicked item changes to clRed - and so on.

I have this code here:

```
var
 CurrentProfile : String; // Global var that stores the caption of the double clicked item.


procedure TForm1.ListView1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if ListView1.Selected <> NIL then CurrentProfile := ListView1.Selected.Caption;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1CustomDrawItem(
Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState;
var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
 if item.Caption = CurrentProfile then begin
  Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
 end else begin 
  Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack; // if not change it back to black
 end;
end;
```

With this code every double clicked item stays in clRed. Why does it not change back to clBlack? Please help. Thank you in advance.

PS.: I use delphi7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double click event handler needs to force a repaint. Call `ListView1.Invalidate` right at the end of that handler. This will force a paint cycle on the list view.

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ListView1.Selected <> NIL then 
  begin
    CurrentProfile := ListView1.Selected.Caption; 
    ListView1.Invalidate;
  end;
end;
```